# Determining if two strings are a substring of a permutation of another String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, permutation

So I am trying to figure out if two strings when combined together are a substring of a permutation of another string.

I have what I believe to be a working solution but it is failing some of the JUnit test cases and I dont have access to the ones that it is failing on.

here is my code with one test case

```
String a="tommarvoloriddle";
String b="lord";
String c="voldemort";
String b= b+c; 
char[] w= a.toCharArray();
char[] k= b.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(k);
Arrays.sort(w);
pw.println(isPermuation(w,k)?"YES":"NO");


static boolean isPermuation(char[] w, char[] k)
{
    boolean found=false;
    for(int i=0; i<k.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j<w.length; j++)
        {
            if(k[i]==w[j])
            {
                j=w.length;
                found=true;
            }
            else
                found=false;
        }
    }


    return found;
}
```

any help getting this to always produce the correct answer would be awesome and help making it more efficient would be great too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+string+permutation

Comment: Sorry... misinterpreted your question.  I didn't see the "substring."

Comment: okay no worries, you see why your solution would fail though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is not a working solution.  However, you don't explain why you thought it might be, so it's hard to figure out what you intended.  I will point out that your code updates `found` unconditionally for each inner loop, so `isPermutation()` will always return the result of the last comparison (which is certainly not what you want).

You did the right thing in sorting the two arrays in the first place -- this is a classic step which should allow you to efficiently evaluate them in one pass.  But then, instead of a single pass, you use a nested loop -- what did you intend here?

A single pass implementation might be something like:

```
static boolean isPermutation(char[] w, char[] k) {
  int k_idx=0;
  for(w_idx=0; w_idx < w.length; ++w_idx) {
    if(k_idx == k.length)
      return true; // all characters in k are present in w
    if( w[w_idx] > k[k_idx] )
      return false;  // found character in k not present in w
    if( w[w_idx] == k[k_idx] )
      ++k_idx;  // character from k corresponds to character from w
  }
  // any remaining characters in k are not present in w
  return k_idx == k.length;
}
```

Comment: I thought it was a working solution, because it worked for all the test cases I generated. Yeah I really goofed with the nested loop, not sure what I was thinking there... thanks for the code though it definitely makes more sense now

Comment: So does this return true for "aaab" and "abbb"?

Answer (score 2):

So we are only interested in whether the two combined strings are a subset of a permutation of another string, meaning that the lengths can in fact differ. So let's say we have:

```
String a = "tommarvoloriddle";
String b = "lord";
String c = "voldemort";

char[] master = a.ToCharArray();
char[] combined = (b + c).ToCharArray();

Arrays.Sort(master);
Arrays.Sort(combined);

System.out.println(IsPermutation(master, combined) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Then our method is:

```
static boolean IsPermutation(char[] masterString, char[] combinedString)
{
    int combinedStringIndex = 0;
    int charsFound = 0;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < masterString.Length; ++i) {
        result = combinedString[combinedStringIndex].CompareTo(masterString[i]);
        if (result == 0) {
            charsFound++;
            combinedStringIndex++;
        }
        else if (result < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return (charsFound == combinedString.Length);
}
```

What the above method does: it starts comparing characters of the two strings. If we have a mismatch, that is, the character at the current `masterString` index does not match the character at the current `combinedString` index, then we simply look at the next character of `masterString` and see if that matches. At the end, we tally the total number of characters matched from our `combinedString`, and, if they are equal to the total number of characters in `combinedString` (its length), then we have established that it is indeed a permutation of `masterString`. If at any point, the current character in `masterString` is numerically greater than the current character in `combinedString` then it means that we will never be able to match the current character, so we give up. Hope that helps.

Comment: For more efficiency on mismatches, you could return `false` if `(combinedString[combinedStringIndex] < masterString[i])`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If two Strings are a permuation of the other you should be able to do this

```
public static boolean isPermuted(Strign s1, String s2) {
     if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

     char[] chars1 = s1.toCharArray();
     char[] chars2 = s2.toCharArray();
     Arrays.sort(chars1);
     Arrays.sort(chars2);
     return Arrays.equals(chars1, chars2);
}
```

This means that when sorted the characters are the same, in the same number.